# Flutter - How to rebuild my page when user logs in using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to hide a `Container` in my app when a user logs in, but my UI won't change even if I use `onAuthStateChanged` or `setState()`

I am using a `StreamBuilder` in my `main.dart` and I am using a dependency that is similar to a Hamburger Menu (https://pub.dev/packages/kf_drawer)  that passes a variable which decides the `Visibility` of my `Container`

```
 return MaterialApp(
      home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (_, snap) {
          if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            if (snap.data != null) {
              return DrawerMenu(firebaseUser: snap.data, visibleLogin: false);
            } else {
              return DrawerMenu(firebaseUser: null, visibleLogin: true);
            }
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

This is my code where the firebase user first passes to the `DrawerMenu()` and then to my `Home()`,

```
KFDrawerItem.initWithPage(
          text: Text(
            'Home',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.white),
          page: Home(
            firebaseUser: widget.firebaseUser,
            visibleLogin: widget.visibleLogin,
          ),
        ),
```

This is the code for my `Container`, however my UI won't update as soon as my user logs in but only when I navigate through the other pages in my app, nor does the state of the app get saved when I re-open my app after quitting it.

```
//Simplified code for example purposes
 Widget login(bool visibleLogin) {
    return Visibility(
      visible: visibleLogin,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want to achieve something like this, the bottom login `Container` disappearing as soon as the user logs in.

BEFORE LOGGING IN - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKfby.png

AFTER LOGGING IN - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zMHB.png

Answer (score 0):

Something might not be right with your stream, are you sure you are getting stream reacting to change if a stream is fine, you can then look to your hamburger it might somehow not working propper.

Comment: The stream notifies me in the debug console, but no changes in my UI.

Answer (score 0):

create a `StreamSubscription` from `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged` in the `initState()` function inside the `DrawerMenu`
to `setState((){})` of the `DrawerMenu` screen depending on the user state;
and remove the `StreamBuilder` from the `MaterialApp`

Comment: It doesn't detect the firebaseUser